# SignalR .NET Client not receiving messages

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr.client

I have a .NET console application that I am practicing signalR with.

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://URL/signalr/");

var hub = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("Hub");

hub.StateChanged += change =>
{
     Console.WriteLine(change.NewState);
};
hub.Received += s =>
{
     Console.WriteLine(s);
};

hub.On<string, string>("processMessage", (group, message) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
});

await hubConnection.Start();

await hub.Invoke<string>("Subscribe", "New group");
```

I see the state changing from Connecting to Connected but I am not getting a "Received" event on the client when the server sends a message.  The server is sending a group message as soon as the client subscribes and I can see the message being sent with the correct "New group" groupname, however I never receive the message on the client.  I also do not receive the processMessage event when the server uses that method.

**Server Code**

```
private void CallBack(string group, string message) 
{
    Clients.Group(group).processMessage(group, message);
}
```

The other method on the server is Subscribe which just sets my inner server to use the CallBack method when it has data available to send to the client.

**Edit**
This works in Javascript it just doesn't seem to work in the .NET client.

Comment: can you please add the server code as well

Comment: Why the close votes and downvote? This is a legit question with efforts.

Comment: Just added the server code.

Comment: Can you put-up your Hub code as well.

Comment: +1 for including the rest of your server-side Hub class in your question. If you can't post the code for your entire Hub, you should at least include the code for your Subscribe method.

Comment: Are you sure your client code is accurate? That code looks wrong, you cannot call `On` on the `hubConnection`, it would be on `hub`... It could well be just a simple typo, I understand, but it is difficult to prove what's wrong if indeed the code is clearly wrong (it wouldn't even compile).

Comment: Sorry yes that should be on the hub.

Comment: don't add /signalr to the connection url, just do `"http://URL/"`

Comment: @Chrisgozd Did you get any solution for the above issue. I'm also facing similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Without full serverside code it's hard to say but I think this part is wrong

```
hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("Hub");
```

as argument you need the name of your hubclass on serverside. For example

```
hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
```

To get more informations on clientside why it fails you can temporary add the following to your HubConnection

```
hubConnection.TraceLevel = TraceLevels.All;
hubConnection.TraceWriter = Console.Out;
```

After adding this you will get further debuging informations in your output section in VS